# node-blocky custom blocks generate

Tags: angular

I am new at blockly, I am using the node component node-blockly in a angular 4 project. The rendering is ok. But now, I am trying to generate custom blocks. For that, I guess that I have to use the build.py generator.
My import in angular 4 is `import Blockly from 'node-blockly/browser';`.
That works. Looking at the browser.js file, I can see that it includes `./lib/blocks_compressed_browser.js` and this file seems not to be regenerated. I would be very happy if someone could provide some tips on how to generate custom blocks in node-blockly.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It will be regenerated when you run `npm run prepublish`, to which pre-requisite is that you run `npm install`. You will then see all re-generated changes in lib folder